# Load a file from a specific directory

Tags: java, file

I have a specified URL that i cant change i.e.

```
/opt/local/java/config/npvr.properties
```

where should i place my file so that the following code can work:

```
String PROPERTIESFILEPATH1 = "/opt/local/java/config/npvr.properties";
File tmPropertiesFile = new File(PROPERTIESFILEPATH);
Properties properties = new Properties();

if (tmPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    .....
}
```

i have tried placing my file in directory shown below but it didn't work:
[image]

My problem is that I can change only the location of property-file without changing the code to solve this problem. Please Help.

Comment: create this folder inside your current package

Comment: Is this general Java, or eclipse-specific (please tag)? Also, what is unclear about the `/` at the beginning of that path? Root folder means root folder.

Comment: You are one layer to high. Store the path within the project-layer.

Comment: By hard-coding the absolute path you can't acheive this functionality. If you are not going to change file name make use of nio2 and search the file in a directory so that you can acheive this.

Comment: nah, print out ``tmPropertiesFile.getAbsolutePath()``

Comment: If you are using linux then add this file /opt/local/java/config/  directory location outside of your project. "OR" in windows C:\opt\local\java\config\ here.

Comment: I suggest just create a file at the specified path you said at "/opt/local/java/config/npvr.properties" and see where it is creating and then place your property file there.

Comment: Thanku Binkan and Sandeep, I found the correct path : "D:\opt\local\java\config\"

Answer (score 3):

The file needs to go in /opt/local/java/config, not [projectdir]/opt/local/java/config. You are putting it in the wrong place

Comment: that is actully i am asking, how to reffer this "/opt/local/java/config" location

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux then add this file `/opt/local/java/config/`  directory location **outside of your project**.

"OR" 
in windows `C:\opt\local\java\config\` here.

Comment: putting that file in that directory structure did't help

Comment: I found the correct path, i.e. "D:\opt\local\java\config\"

Comment: @RahulTyagi so it means your root directory is D:\ instead of C:\

Answer (score 1):

use `getClass().getResourceAsStream` to load property file from relative of class

```
public class Main {

     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
         String PROPERTIESFILEPATH = "/opt/local/java/config/npvr.properties";
         //File tmPropertiesFile = new File(PROPERTIESFILEPATH);
         Properties properties = new Properties();
          InputStream ins=null;
          //ins=new FileInputStream(PROPERTIESFILEPATH);
          ins=new Main().getClass().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIESFILEPATH);
         properties.load(ins);
         System.out.println(properties.get("Hello"));
     }
}
```

Comment: My friend the actual problem is i don't know where the path "/opt/local/java/config/" refer to and other issue is i can't made change in my code because i have to access this method in my jUnit.

Comment: Now i have found the path which "\opt\local\java\config\" refer to i.e. "D:\opt\local\java\config\" which solved the problem